# iOS 9.0 UIDatePicker Class Displays Differently

Tags: ios9

**Problem**

- iOS 9.0 UIDatePicker Class Displays Differently

**Proof**

- Previous Xcode Version (DateCell Sample Code)

  [image: Img1]

  - The Day wheel is visible
- Inline UIDatePicker View Change with Xcode Version 7.0 (DateCell Sample Code)

  [image: Img2]

  - The Day wheel is NOT visible

**My Learning App**

- Has the very same changes as DateCell Sample Code

**Questions**

- Are there Project or Target settings that might solve this User Interface condition?
- Should I spend very much time troubleshooting this User Interface problem?

  - I’m a "Keep It Sample Stupid" kind of person
  - Alway looking for the best practice, based on the most concise problem definition
- Should I be patient and wait for an Apple update that might solve this User Interface issue?
- Is there an Apple Developer submittal process for a perceived Xcode Framework problems?

  - How does the problem defining and solving system work?